# Swap elements in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Suppose I have n number of elements. Which are rendered using ng-repeat in the DOM.

Now I have functionality of move-up and move-down elements. For that I swap two elements according to direction (up or down) using jQuery.
Which works fine.

But after swapping I lost all the bindings of angular. I want the bindings as it is.

Javascript

```
$scope.move = function(event, direction) {
    var div1 = $(event.currentTarget).parent(),
        div2 = direction === 'up' ? $(div1).prev() : $(div1).next(),
        tdiv1 = div1.html(),
        tdiv2 = div2.html();

    div1.html(tdiv2);
    div2.html(tdiv1);
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    {{$index}}

    <div ng-click="move($event, 'up')"> Move up </div>
    <div ng-click="move($event, 'down')"> Move Down </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, after once swapping, I am unable to swap them again.
What I suppose binding must be lost.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why should it work? Change `itemList`, **not** the DOM

Comment: you could create a function like move(index, mode) and just remove the element from itemList and insert it again, you could calculate the position with the index and the mode (up or down)

Comment: @AlonEitan , Thanks for pointing the right way. Please post your answer. I will mark it correct.

Comment: @Kenny Thanks but that's fine :) Glad to help. You can accept dev8080's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define move like this:

```
$scope.move = function(index, direction) {
 var itemToMove = $scope.itemList[index];

 if(direction==='up'){
      $scope.itemList[index] = $scope.itemList[index - 1];
      $scope.itemList[index - 1] = itemToMove;
 } else{
      $scope.itemList[index] = $scope.itemList[index + 1];
      $scope.itemList[index + 1] = itemToMove;
 }
 if(!$scope.$$phase)
         $scope.$apply();
 };
```

Instead of passing in $event to manipulate the DOM, pass in $index to manipulate array:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
{{$index}}

<div ng-click="move($index, 'up')"> Move up </div>
<div ng-click="move($index, 'down')"> Move Down </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your work. But cannot marked you as correct answer. As I got solution before your answer

Comment: @Kenny yeah that's fair ... didn't see the comment of the original answerer.

Comment: @Kenny Please accept this answer (If it helps you), it's much better than my simple comment